# Running Scala Jar with Spark-Submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, spark-submit

I've compiled a spark-scala script to a JAR and I want to run it with spark-submit. But I'm having this error:

```
2020-01-07 13:03:02,190 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, nifi resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
2020-01-07 13:03:02,192 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
2020-01-07 13:03:03,109 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2020-01-07 13:03:03,826 WARN deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2: Failed to load hello.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:806)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2020-01-07 13:03:03,857 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
2020-01-07 13:03:03,858 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-a8cc1ba6-3643-4646-82a3-4b44f4487105
```

This is my code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("quest9")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("quest9").master("local").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._

    val zip_codes = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/hdfs/Documents/quest_9/doc/zip.csv")
    val census = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/hdfs/Documents/quest_9/doc/census.csv")

    census.createOrReplaceTempView("census")
    zip_codes.createOrReplaceTempView("zip")


    val query = census.as("census").join((zip_codes.where($"City" === "Inglewood").where($"County" === "Los Angeles").as("zip")),Seq("Zip_Code"),"inner").select($"census.Total_Males".as("male"),$"census.Total_Females".as("female")).distinct()
    query.show()
    val queryR = query.repartition(5)
    queryR.write.parquet("/home/hdfs/Documents/population/census/IDE/census.parquet")

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

I think my problem is that im using scala object instead of a class, but I'm not sure.

I run the spark-submit like this

```
spark-submit \
--class hello \
/home/hdfs/IdeaProjects/untitled/out/artifacts/quest_jar/quest.jar
```

Anyone solved this error before?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify a package name for both spark-submit and your object.

For instance :

```
spark-submit \
--class com.my.package.hello \
/home/hdfs/IdeaProjects/untitled/out/artifacts/quest_jar/quest.jar
```

and

```
package com.my.package

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object hello {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I did, I created a dummy package just to try it out, and called it "test", it still said It couldnt find it. Is there a difference between using an object or a class?

Comment: An object is a singleton and your Main is a singleton. It's fine.

Comment: Can you run something like `jar tvf /home/hdfs/IdeaProjects/untitled/out/artifacts/quest_jar/quest.jar
` ? It will list your jar content

Comment: and I've ran the code straight from the IDE and it worked without an issue

Comment: No doubt about it. But now we have to figure out why submitting your jar fails

Comment: Could it be a spark problem and not the jar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205526/discussion-between-baitmbarek-and-joao-bernardo).

Comment: Chatroom summary: build the jar using `sbt package` instead if the IntelliJ UI. I had the same problem as OP and using sbt also worked. However, I would prefer to use IntelliJ's functionality (Build>Build Artificacts). Why does that not work?